# Is a complex polynomial a regular covering? What is its group of deck tranformations?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces

We know that a complex polynomial $P$ of degree $n$ is an $n$-sheeted covering from
$$\{\mathbb{C} - P^{-1}\{\text{critical values of }P\}\} \to \{\mathbb{C} - \{\text{critical values of }P\}\}. $$ 
So the question is how to determine whether such a cover is regular or not, and its group of deck transformations.

The specific example I was trying was $P(Z)=Z^3 - 3Z$. The critical values are $\{2,-2\}$. So the group is $F_2$, i.e. the free group on 2 generators, and $$P^{-1}\{\text{critical values of }P\} = \underset{\text{corr. to }2}{\{2,-1\}} \cup \underset{\text{corr. to }-2}{\{-2,1\}}.$$ So here the group is $F_4$. I see the facts that a small simple loop around $2$ maps to a simple loop around $2$, and small simple loop around $-1$ maps to a double loop around $2$. And similar for preimage of $-2$. We know that if the image of the fundamental group of domain is normal in fundamental group of codomain, then the covering is regular. So can we fix a point and say that a simple loop just going around 2 will map to a simple loop going around 2 and similarly for other points? I guess not (because then the image would be whole group, which contradicts the fact that it is a $3$-sheeted cover).

So how to proceed? Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Since one has a $3$-sheeted (unbranched holomorphic) covering of a connected Riemann surface, the deck group $G$ has at most $3$ elements (see Remark to Definition 5.5, Forster - *Lectures on Riemann Surfaces*).

Let $\varphi$ be a (non trivial) deck transformation, by definition:
\begin{equation}
\forall z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{\pm1,\pm2\}\equiv Y,\,\varphi(z)^3-3\varphi(z)=z^3-3z\\
\varphi(z)^3-z^3=3[\varphi(z)-z]\\
[\varphi(z)-z][\varphi(z)^2+z\varphi(z)+z^2]=3[\varphi(z)-z]\\
\varphi(z)^2+z\varphi(z)+z^2-3=0\\
\varphi(z)=\frac{-z\pm|12-3z^2|e^{\textstyle\frac{arg(12-3z^2)}{2}i}}{2};
\end{equation}
by all this:
\begin{equation}
G=\left\{Id_Y,\varphi_{-}(z)=\frac{-z-|12-3z^2|e^{\textstyle\frac{arg(12-3z^2)}{2}i}}{2},\varphi_{+}(z)=\frac{-z+|12-3z^2|e^{\textstyle\frac{arg(12-3z^2)}{2}i}}{2}\right\}\cong\mathbb{Z}_3,
\end{equation}
where $|\cdot|$ and $arg(\cdot)$ are the module and the mainvalue of $\cdot$, respectively.

Comment: Why does this work? Over the complex numbers we cannot define a global continuous square root function, so it seems that your proposed deck transformations are not well-defined

Comment: If you write those square roots in the exponential notation, you will see that all is right.

Comment: You mean writing $\sqrt{12-3z^2} = \exp(\frac{1}{2} \log(12-3z^2))$? That still needs a global logarithm, since $12-3z^2$ is surjective in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: No, absolutely not! I edited my answer. Give me a feed back. O:)

Comment: I believe that your edit does not avoid your problem, since we still cannot define a continuous argument function in the whole complex plane

Comment: Why? The complex exponential function is $2\pi$-periodic with respect to imaginary part of complex numbers!

Comment: If we change the argument by $2\pi$ here then the value inside the exponential shifts by $\pi i$ because of the division by $2$, and so we don't get the same value

Comment: The functions $\varphi_{-}$ and $\varphi_{+}$ indeed do not define continuous functions on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{\pm 1,\pm 2\}$. The group of deck transformations in this case is trivial; see my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1707382/deck-transformation-of-p-y-to-x-z-mapsto-z3-3z/4620481#4620481.